# Byte array to integer

Tags: java, android-studio

How to convert byte array to int in java. I am building Bluetooth app on which I received a message in byte array then I convert it to string it converted successfully but I also want it in integer form

Comment: We'd need to see the specification for what is in the byte array, but in general `DataInputStream` will work.

Comment: Could you include example? For now it looks like you want to convert entire byte array to *single* integer which may be impossible for long byte arrays. This suggests that you may want to convert it to *more* integers, maybe array of integers. But then do you want to convert single byte to single integer or 4 bytes to single integer? Or maybe even other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in Java any more, but something like this might work.

```
int[] intArray = int[byteArray.length];
for( int i =0 ; i< byteArray.length; i++){
    intArray[i] = byteArray[i];
}
```